# Wrap Ruby methods at run-time to intercept method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a parent class that is similar to ActiveRecord, and I'm trying to open the class on load in our test suite. I want to wrap the `initialize` method so that it maintains a list of all of the subclasses that are initialized so I can make sure that all of the data for those classes is cleaned up between tests. Running a full wipe between tests winds up being too inefficient (plus I'm just interested in what the code would like to do this is).

My goal is to insert a new `initialize` method in the inheritance tree and just call `super`. All the while maintaining some list of all of the instantiated classes inside the parent class.

My attempt so far:

```
class NewActiveRecord
  @@__instantiated_classes = Set.new

  def initialize(*args)
    @@__instantiated_classes.add(self.class)
    super *args
  end

  def self.reset_tracking
    @@__instantiated_classes = Set.new
  end

  def self.get_instantiated_classes
    @@__instantiated_classes.to_a
  end
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
   teardown do
      NewActiveRecord.get_instantiated_classes.each {|c| c.destroy_all}
      NewActiveRecord.reset_tracking
   end
end
```

Basically I want to wrap all methods that are called on subclasses of some parent to send their class to some predefined object their class

Comment: Why not use something more standard like database_cleaner to clean stuff up between tests? And set up your tests to run in transactions based on this article: http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/ A transaction seems faster than calling `destroy` on a collection of objects that you've maintained through the test run.

Comment: Performance reasons. We're not using a relational database in this case (using Cassandra). I'm not totally up to speed on the reason as I just started about a month ago

Answer (score 0):

Did some exploring today and came up with the following solution. I'm still not sure how to unspy something yet though:

```
module Spy
  def self.on_instance_method(mod, method, &block)
    mod.class_eval do
      # Stash the old method
      old_method = instance_method(method)

      # Create a new proc that will call both our block and the old method
      proc = Proc.new do
        block.call if block
        old_method.bind(self).call
      end

      # Bind that proc to the original module
      define_method(method, proc)
    end
  end

  def self.on_class_method(mod, method, &block)
    mod.class_eval do
      # Stash the old method
      old_method = singleton_method(method)

      # Create a new proc that will call both our block and the old method
      proc = Proc.new do
        block.call if block
        old_method.call
      end

      # Bind that proc to the original module
      define_singleton_method(method, proc)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage from my tests looks like:

```
count = 0
Spy.on_instance_method(FakeClass, :value) { count += 1 }
fake = FakeClass.new(6)
fake.value.must_equal 6
count.must_equal 1
```